# Is there a good searchable database of D&D adventures?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures

I have shelves and shelves of RPG books, and a lot of it's D&D.  I have every Dungeon magazine from #1 on.  But for some reason I can never find the right adventure for what I need.

What I'm thinking of is a database where I can search on the adventures mainly by level and by relevant tags.

I've found a couple online DBs like the [Dungeon Magazine Index](http://www.intwischa.com/dungeon/), but they usually don't allow useful searching, and they don't let you multiselect.  Like I'm not picky about whether an adventure is for 3e, 3.5e, or Pathfinder, but usually they don't let you search on that.  And poor data entry is a problem; like searching for level 5 doesn't match "4-6".  And it should search on extended attributes or even user-added tags - if an adventure is set in Greyhawk in an Egyptian-themed pyramid tomb in a desert and has undead and stuff, it would be tagged "greyhawk egyptian pyramid undead mummy desert".  Ideally it would include "Official" (WotC/Paizo), third party/OGL, and Dungeon mag stuff, from all editions.

Like my current use case is "I want an adventure for 5th level PCs.  I'm running Pathfinder, but 3.5e/3e are OK.  I'm interested in it having one or more of the following attributes - pirates, urban, horror, flooding, shadow."  I basically have to rack my memory, leaf through my shelf of published modules, and eye the shelf of Dungeon magazines and sigh.

What databases/tools exist that might allow this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rpggeek.com database can be searched, and has the information in the database, but not in a readily searchable field. It does, however, have various series searches, and most have cover scans visible in the series listing, so you can readily examine the levels available.

Comment: Perhaps I'm unused to that search, but I can't even figure out how to narrow it down to D&D adventures.  I can narrow it down to adventures...  And by publisher, but that's a poor cousin to what game system.  Also, many products don't have level ranges on their cover, instead having them on the back or first page.

Comment: Start by searching for the system. You'll get a sh*load of responses for AD&D. Then click on the system entry for the version you're looking at. THEN switch the list to show adventures. Or, search for a particular series title, like "G1"... and click on the series label. It's uncomfortable to use at first, but it's the best RPG dbase out there. And there's already a request ticket on adding level ranges and player ranges to the readily searchable fields.

Answer (score 5):

http://intwischa.com/dungeon *does* match a "level 4-6" if you specify 5 as the operator. And I'm not sure what you mean by "multiselect," but you can specify a search on all criteria at the same time (for instance, level 5, greyhawk, 2nd edition).

When I built the thing in 2006, though, I did intend to add user tags to it... I just never came back to the project after building it once. Now, five years later, I'm surprised to see the thing is still getting used, and I'm thinking about adding features. I welcome comments! (You'll see that you can now comment on the index page)

Answer (score 2):

For older editions, the [Acaeum](http://www.acaeum.com) has these matrices cross indexing the older modules with various level ranges.

[For AD&D](http://www.acaeum.com/library/addmodchart.html)

[For D&D](http://www.acaeum.com/library/ddmodchart.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following database of adventures might suit your needs..

[RPG Archive](http://www.rpgarchive.com/index.php?page=adv&title=&sort=Alpha&sysid=37&index=11)
The adventures are not "searchable" but they can be filtered according to multiple criteria.

I suspect that filterable indices like [intwisha Dungeon Index](http://www.intwischa.com/dungeon/) might be the best you can do - if you could search, what criteria would you search on?

Carl

Comment: I'd want to search on what the adventure's about or is in it. There's a million "level 5 D&D" adventures and a list of those doesn't really help anyone. Simple user tagging would do it (keyword indexing the blurbs is probably not nearly as helpful because they are often not very descriptive). I want an aquatic adventure, or one with undead, or whatever. Perhaps details like how long it is...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but some of the links in some answers no longer seem to work. [Campaign Crawler](http://www.campaigncrawler.com) is a new one that allows searching of campaigns. It's a work in progress but constantly being updated.

Edit:
Some previous answer links that appear to **no longer work** are:

- http://intwischa.com/dungeon
- http://www.rpgarchive.com

Comment: Thanks for helping add to the accumulated wisdom of the site. If you get a moment, would you mind dropping a comment on the answers where you found broken links? Even if the original author doesn't come back to do maintenance, it might encourage some good Samaritan to try to recover the resource.

Comment: @nitsua60 Never mind though; this is just an old shopping question that is showing the reason they're no longer accepted: dead links, unmaintainability, and answers that don't address the details of the question.