# High Level (16-20) Adventures

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

My party is currently working their way through Castle Whiterock.  It's designed to run a D&D 3.5 party from 1st to 15th.  We're playing it using Pathfinder rules and are part-way through level 9 and just about to hit 10th level so we are roughly right on track for the advancement progression.  Assuming our current rate we are expecting to be roughly 16th/17th when we finish up the dungeon.  (Assuming we survive of course!)

It's been discussed that we'd like to continue with our party after Castle Whiterock but it doesn't look like there are any Dungeon Crawl Classics that are in the range of levels 16-20+.  After doing some research I've managed to find a couple adventures for either Pathfinder ([Coliseum Morpheon](http://paizo.com/store/byCompany/c/cubicle7/pathfinderRPG/v5748btpy8gph)) or D&D ([Bastion of Broken Souls](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786926562)).  My DM isn't sold on either of these.  I'm looking for other high level D&D/Pathfinder adventures in that range of 16-20 or more preferably some web resources that list adventures in this range.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following D&D 3.0/3.5 adventures of level 16-20 ran in Dungeon magazine, or were released for free on the WotC website:

**Level 16**

- Demonblade (Dungeon #97)
- Rock and the Hard Place (Dungeon #91)
- Bright Mountain King (Dungeon #142)
- The Library of Last Resort (Dungeon #132)
- Thirteen Cages (Dungeon #114)
- [Black Rain](https://web.archive.org/web/20181008022753/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20020427a) (WotC website)

**Level 17**

- Into the Maw (Dungeon #147)
- The Twisted Run (Dungeon #129)
- The Greater Halls (Dungeon #139)
- [The Haunting Lodge](https://web.archive.org/web/20181008022850/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20021130a) (WotC website)
- [The Thunder Below](https://web.archive.org/web/20190503183558/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20041225a) (WotC website)

**Level 18**

- Diplomacy (Dungeon #144)
- Gates of Oblivion (Dungeon #136)
- Kings of the Rift (Dungeon #133)
- The Lich-Queen's Beloved (Dungeon #100)
- Root of Evil (Dungeon #122)
- Strike on Shatterhorn (Dungeon #115)
- Vlindarian's Vault (Dungeon #141)
- Wells of Darkness (Dungeon #148)
- [Force of Nature](https://web.archive.org/web/20181008022854/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20040326a) (WotC website)
- [War of Dragons](https://web.archive.org/web/20181008022840/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20040227a) (WotC website)
- Prisoner of the Castle Perilous (WotC online Dungeon #153)

**Level 19**

- Asylum (Dungeon #116)
- Enemies of My Enemy (Dungeon #149)
- Into the Wormcrawl Fissue (Dungeon #134)

**Level 20**

- Dawn of a New Age (Dungeon #135)
- Prince of Demons (Dungeon #150)
- The Razing of Redshore (Dungeon #92)
- Heart of Hellfire Mountain (Dungeon #140)
- [An Icy Heart](https://web.archive.org/web/20181008022833/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20020125a) (WotC website)
- The Essence of Evil (WotC online Dungeon #152)

Answer (score 2):

Paizo's site has a faceted navigation view called the "[Adventure Finder](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventureFinder)" which lists adventures by level. It includes third party adventures.  As of this writing there's only 11 for levels 16-20, but it's a starting point.

Similarly on RPGNow they have navigation that lets you narrow down on, say, [high level Pathfinder adventures](http://www.rpgnow.com/browse.php?filters=0_2114_44235_0_0). Their metadata generally sucks however, and many of the 46 matches for that filter are wildly inapplicable.

See also [Is there a good searchable database of D&D adventures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/is-there-a-good-searchable-database-of-dd-adventures)

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if any of the adventure paths near that level?

Comment: No, they all end at or before.